# PayPal Payflow Pro recent transactions

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

How can I get recent transactions with Payflow Pro API?
I can Submit Transaction but could not find how to pull transactions which are processed before.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know you can't get a list of recent transactions from the api. You can keep the pnref or custref and use a inquiry transaction ([page 38](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf)) to get the status of individual transactions though.